# Bat file find folder of file

Tags: batch-file

So my many attempts to search for a solution have resulted in a million ways to find the folder of the bat file being executed, however what I am looking to do is find the folder for the filename being passed to the bat file.

Example:

```
C:\Temp\runthis.bat "C:\Blah\Ah Argh\rage.txt"
```

I want to get a string within that bat file that is simply "C:\Blah\Ah Argh\", alternatively I would also be able to work with getting a string of "rage.txt"

Editing to explain why: Looking to check for the filename within another txt file which is the directory listing of a ftp server to verify that a file successfully uploaded to it. Then if successful I need to move the file to a subfolder of the original folder \uploaded\ but we have many of these folders setup so I can't hard code it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
if %1X==X echo Syntax: %0 "path"

rem  The for loop doesn't actually loop. You can split strings with it, but in 
rem  this case we don't. So there is only one iteration in which %%X will 
rem  contain the full path.

rem  Pass it %1, which is the first parameter. Note the quotes, which are 
rem  required if you don't add quotes around the parameter and optional (but 
rem  still valid) when you do.

for /F "delims=|" %%X in ("%1") do (

  rem  FOR LOOP variables can be used with certain modifiers, preceeded by a 
  rem  tilde. In this case I'm using d and p, which stand for drive and path,
  rem  effectively trimming the file name from the path.

  echo %%~dpX

  rem The ~n modifier selects the file name only. ~x is for extension

  echo %%~nxX
)
```

Comment: I've updated the original post with a better example, using the above example the current code only works without the surrounding "s on the arguement(the first version you posted worked with the surrounding "s) but either way it gives me C:\Blah\, I would assume because of the space?

Comment: To reclarify...
`C:\Temp\runthis.bat "C:\Blah\Ah Argh\rage.txt"` produces an error
`C:\Temp\runthis.bat C:\Blah\Ah Argh\rage.txt` produces no error, but returns "C:\Blah\"

Comment: I've posted an updated version. The check for input is now 'quote proof' (although you didn't ask for that). I've added a delimiter. Apparently, the delimiter is a space by default, but by specifying another, you can prevent the string being split on spaces. I chose a `|` because that cannot be part of a file name. I also added the modifier `x` to echoing the file name, so its extension is echoed as well.

Comment: This works, but it is overly complicated. A simple FOR would work, no need for FOR /F: `for %%X in (%1) do (...`. You can assume that the value of %1 will be quoted if needed. By adding your own quotes, the code would break if quotes are already within `%1`. But simpler yet, the same modifiers you use for `%%X` are also available for `%1`. A safer check to see if `%1` exists is `if "%~1"=="" ...`. You also probably want to `exit /b` if the calling syntax is wrong.

Comment: Nice. The modifiers don't work on environment variables, but apparently you can use them for the parameterers. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
The file path is %~dp1
The file name is %~nx1
```

The parameter modifiers are the same as for FOR variables.

Type 'HELP CALL' from a command prompt for a full list of parameter modifiers.

Comment: Nice. The modifiers don't work on environment variables, but apparently you can use them for the parameterers. Didn't know that.

Comment: +1, this is definitely a more simple answer and it perfectly addresses the scenario, but the other is helpful for any re-referencing of the files via strings and is compatable with not having ""s, the problem I ran into with this solution when I first ran into it is losing the ""s would kill it, as you can't %~dp* etc